# How to get the message form php page to Html page?

Tags: php, html

I was wondering how I could get the message from my php page to my html message. When the user successfully creates a user, I want to get the "success" message from php to the html.

html:

```
<form class="" action="insertUser.php" method="post">
    <input id="formInput" name="firstname" value="" placeholder="Firstname"> <br>

    <input id="btn" type="submit" name="" value="Create">
    <h2><?php echo $result ?></h2>
</form>
```

php:

```
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['firstname']);

$stmt = "INSERT INTO user (firstname) VALUES('$firstname')";
if(empty($firstname) ){
    echo $result = "added";
    header('Location: index.php', true, 303);
    exit;
} else {
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $stmt)) {
        echo "erro";

        header('Location: index.php', true, 303);
        exit;
    }else {
        echo "Error: " .mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
```

I did not include the connection file. The function works, its only the echo part that does not work. I get the error message "Fatal error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by appending the message as a get var onto the header url which is a bit unorthodox

```
$stmt = "INSERT INTO user (firstname) VALUES('$firstname')";
  if (mysqli_query($conn, $stmt)) {
    $msg = "success";

    header('Location: index.php?msg='.$msg);
        exit;
  }else {
        $error = "erro";
        header('Location: index.php?msg='.$error);
  }
```

in your html you would call the get var using:

```
<h2><?php echo $_GET['msg'] ?></h2>
```

or you could store the error message in a session:

```
     //include at top of your script
     session_start();


$stmt = "INSERT INTO user (firstname) VALUES('$firstname')";
  if (mysqli_query($conn, $stmt)) {
    $msg = "success";

    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Success message"
    header('Location: index.php');

  }else {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Error message"
        header('Location: index.php');
  }
```

and on your recipient php file of the error message, also include `session_start()` and simple echo the `$_SESSION['error']` like so

in your html you would call the get var using:

```
<h2><?php echo $_SESSION['msg'] ?></h2>
```

Comment: So I tried this, but it did not work. Not sure why though.

Comment: Hm.. Still seems to not work, I done get any "success" message

Comment: which method did you try?

Comment: the one at the top

Comment: feel free to send me an email on my stack overflow profile and i'll take a futher look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165369/discussion-between-alison-and-juakali92).

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting the user back to index.php.

You have two options to pass the message to index.php

1. You can use query param to pass the message. In that case change

> ```
> header('Location: index.php', true, 303);
> ```

to

> ```
> header('Location: index.php?response=success', true, 303);
> ```

and

> echo $result

to

> echo $_GET['response']

Note: This scenario is xss prone, please use appt sanitizing before echoing the message.

2. Use Session to set the message.

Answer (score 0):

The sql was potentially vulnerable to `SQL injection` so you ought to use `prepared statements` when dealing with user supplied data like this. It has already been suggested that using a session variable would be one way - this is how I might have done it.

Be wary of displaying too much information if there is some sort of error with the database query - fine for development but not in production.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['useradded']='Unable to add user';

    /* include db connection */

    try{
        $firstname=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'firstname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        if( $firstname ){

            $sql='insert into `user` ( `firstname` ) values( ? )';
            $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );

            if( !$stmt )throw new Exception('Failed to prepare sql');

            $stmt->bind_param( 's', $firstname );
            $result=$stmt->execute();

            if( $result && $stmt->affected_rows==1 ){
                $_SESSION['useradded']='User added';
            } else {
                throw new Exception('error adding user');
            }

            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();

            exit( header('Location: index.php') );

        } else {
            throw new Exception('firstname is required');
        }
    }catch( Exception $e ){
        $conn->close();
        $_SESSION['error']=$e->getMessage();
        exit( header('Location: index.php') );
    }
?>



<form action='insertUser.php' method='post'>
    <input id='formInput' name='firstname' placeholder='Firstname'> <br>
    <input type='submit' value='Create'>
    <?php
        if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
            if( !empty( $_SESSION['error'] ) ) {
                printf('<h2 class="error">%s</h2>', $_SESSION['error'] );
                unset( $_SESSION['error'] );
            } else {
                printf('<h2 class="success">%s</h2>', !empty( $_SESSION['useradded'] ) ? $_SESSION['useradded'] : '' );
                unset( $_SESSION['useradded'] );
            }
        }
    ?>
</form>
```